# Create a class using execute anonymous

Tags: apex

Is-it possible de create a class to use it later in the same code in  execute anonymous?
Here is an example of i want to do (i do not want to execute this code but it has the same principle of i want to do):

```
public class AccountClass {
  protected Account account;

  public AccountClass(){
    this.account = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account LIMIT 1 ORDER BY CreatedDate Desc]
  }

  public String Account getAccountName(){
    return this.account.Name;
  }
}

AccountClass accountClass = AccountClass();
System.debug(accountClass.getAccountName);
```

the code is simple but when i executed, i got the following error:

```
Unexpected token 'public'.
```

Comment: The answer here is "yes". Generally speaking, questions that can be answered with a simple yes/no aren't great fits for this site. It would probably be faster for you to try to do the thing you're asking about yourself than wait for someone like me to chime in. If you try it, and it fails, asking if it's possible along with the error message you're getting would make a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Need a semi-colon after your SOQL query, put LIMIT 1 after ORDER BY, and remove 'ACCOUNT' from getAccountName().

```
this.account = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account  ORDER BY CreatedDate Desc LIMIT 1];
```

(not much point in ordering if you only have one record)

```
public String getAccountName(){
    return this.account.Name;
  }
```

When you call getAccountName method need to put parentheses after:

```
System.debug(accountClass.getAccountName());
```

If you create a apex file and drop your code in there, it'll give you error messages to show you where you are going wrong, then copy paste out to execute anonymous (though that might defeat the purpose of doing it in execute anonymous!)

Comment: thanks, here the right code
 ````
public class AccountClass {
  protected Account account;

  public AccountClass(){
    this.account = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account  ORDER BY CreatedDate Desc LIMIT 1];
  }

  public String  getAccountName(){
    return this.account.Name;
  }
}

AccountClass accountClass = new AccountClass();
System.debug(accountClass.getAccountName());
````